# How to create a function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

1.I have the data like below:

```
[{
    "BatchConfigName": "End1",

    "EndDateTime": "2019-01-06T11:10:00"
  },
  {
    "BatchConfigName": "End2 - Non-Gas",

    "EndDateTime": "2019-01-07T05:54:00"
  },
  {
    "BatchConfigName": "Secure",

    "EndDateTime": "2019-01-07T04:48:00"
  }
}
```

2. i want to create the typescript function that assign this data like

   ```
   var datawebsiteViewsChart = {
   labels: ['End1', 'End2 - Non-Gas', 'Secure'],
   series: [
       [11: 10, 05: 54, 04: 48]
   ]
   };
   ```

   None

Comment: @ArvindChaudhary I understand your struggles, but please try to understand that some times these struggles help you become a better programmer. You can always try tutorial web sites to learn more. Here is an example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/

Answer (score 0):

```
function map(data) {
    const labels = [];
    const series = [];

    for (itemKey of data) {
        labels.push(itemKey);
        series.push(data[itemKey]);
    }

    return {
        labels,
        series
    };
}
```